# Unresolvable perl error?

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array

```
use strict;
my @array = ();
my @nums = [3, 4];
foreach my $i ( 0 .. 10 ) {
    foreach my $j ( 0 .. 10 ) {
        $nums[0] = 4+1;
        push @{ $array[$i] }, @nums;
    }
}
print $array[6][2][0]. "\n";
```

As one can see if they run the code, this doesn't run properly. However, if you comment out the line "$nums[0] = 4+1;", it runs fine. What is going on? Can only immutable arrays be pushed onto others?

Comment: `my @array = ();` is better written as `my @array;`, since they are functionally identical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@nums` is an array, and you assign to an array reference (with brackets `[]`). So, change it to a  proper array declaration: `my @nums = (3, 4);`

```
use strict;
use Data::Dump;

my @array = ();
my @nums = (3, 4);
foreach my $i ( 0 .. 10 ) {
    foreach my $j ( 0 .. 10 ) {
        $nums[0] = 4+1;
        push @{ $array[$i] }, @nums;
    }
}

dd @array;

#-- output:
(
  [5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4],
  [5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4],
  [5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4],
  [5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4],
  [5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4],
  [5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4],
  [5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4],
  [5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4],
  [5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4],
  [5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4],
  [5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4],
)
```

Comment: New question: When I call a subfunction on an array in the outer array, how do I do it? It keeps telling me I'm using an "uninitialized value." (This isn't the actual array of arrays I'm using in my project, but I made the changes you said.)

Comment: A new question should be asked as a new question. Not tacked on to an existing question in a comment.

Comment: I did that, but I thought I'd put it here anyway since they were somewhat related.